# Why is the trace of this object non-negative?

Tags: matrices, trace, hermitian-matrices

$\phi$ is an arbitrary superposition of powers of a single hermitian matrix, $M^k$:

$$\phi =\sum_{k} \alpha_{k} M^{k}$$

Why is the following statement true?

$$\langle \mathrm{tr}\left(\phi^\dagger \phi \right)\rangle \geq 0$$

I have recently asked a related question, [Why is the trace of a hermitian matrix raised to an even power greater than or equal to 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712669/why-is-the-trace-of-a-hermitian-matrix-raised-to-an-even-power-greater-than-or-e/3712963#3712963). I understand that the trace over any $M^{2k}$ would be non-negative. But here the product $\phi^\dagger \phi$ will in general have odd powers, and so there could be negative terms in the trace, according to my understanding.

I am coming across this statement in Eq. (3.9) of https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08387

Answer (score 1):

Actually if $M$ is any matrix we have $\text{tr(M*M)} \geq 0$. This is clear if $M$ is diagonalizable and diagonalizable matrices are dense in all matrices.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Does that address the matter of the $\langle \mathrm{tr}\left(\phi^\dagger\phi\right)\rangle$ object? My apologies if it does and I have missed your point.

Comment: @SergeCarrefax Perhaps I have misunderstood the notation. It looks like $\phi$ is a sum of a bunch of matrices times a bunch of scalars, so is itself a matrix.